# Safari Mobile - Problem with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website after deploy. On mobile version of Safari, the  background image renders very badly, looks like 144p. I checked the website on Android - Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera - and the website is working fine.

Does anyone know the solution?

```
.driver {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("/assets/img/unrevied/brooke-lark-pGM4sjt_BdQ-unsplash.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px 20px;

    @include overlay(#000, 0.2);

    @media (max-width: width 1000px) {
        background-position: left center;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

is not supported on Safari IOS.

See `https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment`
You may have to do something like show the background-image with size cover.